# How to copy records from local database to master remote database

Tags: sql, sql-server-express

I am using a local sql server express 2012 database to temporarily store data from a pc application.  Once a day, I would like to take all the new records and copy them from the local database to a master database which is located on a remote system.  Most of the tools I have seen are designed to copy complete tables and not just new data.  What are some tools that are commonly used for this process?

Comment: Did you try writing a query joining the two tables (remote and local) but use an outer join on the primary key to see what is new?

Comment: What is it in the local database that identifies the data as 'new'?

Comment: I have a flag in the table that just notes if the record was copied.  I think I can do this using the SQL Server Inport and Export Wizard, but I really need 2 queries to execute.  The first copies the record, the second updates the copy flag in the local copy.  Is this possible?